# Poor IPsec over GRE performances

Tags: ipsec, gre, racoon, netbsd

I have set up an IPsec over GRE connection with a remote host, both are *NetBSD* 6.1 based. The "client" is connected to the Internet through a 400Mbps fiber
connection. The "server" is located on a 10Gbps network. Both machines have
1Gbps NICs which behave perfectly, meaning they both reach the link speed limit
when transferring data outside the IPsec tunnel.
When doing a transfer through the tunnel, speed drops at a factor 5 to 10:

direct connection:

`/dev/null            27%[====>                 ] 503.19M  45.3MB/s   eta 83s`

IPsec connection:

`/dev/null             2%[                      ]  47.76M  6.05MB/s   eta 5m 3s`

The tunnel is setup this way:

On the server, which is a *NetBSD domU* running on a *debian/amd64 dom0*:

```
$ cat /etc/ifconfig.xennet0
# server interface
up
inet 192.168.1.2 netmask 255.255.255.0
inet 172.16.1.1 netmask 0xfffffffc alias
$ cat /etc/ifconfig.gre0 
create
tunnel 172.16.1.1 172.16.1.2 up
inet 172.16.1.5 172.16.1.6 netmask 255.255.255.252
```

IPsec traffic is forwarded from dom0's public IP to the domU's `xennet0` interfacethrough `iptables` NAT rules:

```
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 500 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.2:500 
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p esp -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.2 
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p ah -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.2
```

On the client:

```
$ cat /etc/ifconfig.vlan8 
# client public interface
create
vlan 8 vlanif re0
!dhcpcd -i $int
inet 172.16.1.2 netmask 0xfffffffc alias
$ cat /etc/ifconfig.gre1 
create
tunnel 172.16.1.2 172.16.1.1 up
inet 172.16.1.6 172.16.1.5 netmask 255.255.255.252
```

On `racoon`'s side, I tried various hash / encryption algorithms combinations, even `enc_null`, but nothing changes really, transfer is still stuck at a 6MB/s max.

```
remote node.public.ip {
     exchange_mode main;
     lifetime time 28800 seconds;
     proposal {
         encryption_algorithm blowfish;
         hash_algorithm sha1;
         authentication_method pre_shared_key;
         dh_group 2;
     }
     generate_policy off;
}

sainfo address 172.16.1.1/30 any address 172.16.1.2/30 any {
     pfs_group 2;
     encryption_algorithm blowfish;
     authentication_algorithm hmac_sha1;
     compression_algorithm deflate;
     lifetime time 3600 seconds;
}
```

On the client:

```
remote office.public.ip {
     exchange_mode main;
     lifetime time 28800 seconds;
     proposal {
         encryption_algorithm blowfish;
         hash_algorithm sha1;
         authentication_method pre_shared_key;
         dh_group 2;
     }
     generate_policy off;
}

sainfo address 172.16.1.2/30 any address 172.16.1.1/30 any {
     pfs_group 2;
     encryption_algorithm blowfish;
     authentication_algorithm hmac_sha1;
     compression_algorithm deflate;
     lifetime time 3600 seconds;
}
```

The tunnel establishes with no issue, the only problem here is transfer drop.
Again, when transferring from / to the server from / to the client without
tunnel, speed is optimal, drop occurs **only** through IPsec.

Both machines are intel-based CPUs running at 2+GHz, plenty of memory and very
little CPU time consumed by anything else than forwarding / NAT.

Has anyone witnessed such a behaviour? Any idea on where to look further?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

If you didn't tweak MTU, you may have post-fragmentation issues (fragmentation occuring after encryption) that is well explained in this documentation: http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/interfaces_modules/services_modules/vspa/configuration/guide/ivmsw_book/ivmvpnb.html#wp2047965

You should try to reduce MTU inside the tunnel by 82 bytes (GRE + IPSec headers).

Comment: Yes I did that, even forced MSS with `iptables` on the server side, but no matter what, I get a massive speed drop. FWIW, I lowered involved MTUs at values as low as 1360 without success.